# Don't move tiles at board puzzle at godot 3.5.2

Tags: gd, godot, gdscript, godot3

I started making puzzles in Godot 3.5.2 from a video tutorial.
I entered these codes for a tile.

```
extends TextureButton

var number

signal tile_pressed
signal slide_completed


func set_text(new_number):
    number = new_number
    $Number/Label.text = str(number)

func set_sprite(new_frame, size, tile_size):
    var sprite = $Sprite

    update_size(size, tile_size)

    sprite.set_hframes(size)
    sprite.set_vframes(size)
    sprite.set_frame(new_frame)

func update_size(size, tile_size):
    var new_size = Vector2(tile_size, tile_size)
    set_size(new_size)
    $Number.set_size(new_size)
    $Number/ColorRect.set_size(new_size)
    $Number/Label.set_size(new_size)
    $Panel.set_size(new_size)

    var to_scale = size * (new_size / $Sprite.texture.get_size())
    $Sprite.set_scale(to_scale)


func set_sprite_texture(texture):
    $Sprite.set_texture(texture)

func slide_to(new_position, duration):
    var tween = $Tween
    tween.interpolate_property(self, "rect_position", null, new_position, duration,Tween.TRANS_QUART, Tween.EASE_OUT)
    tween.start()

func set_number_visible(state):
    $Number.visible = state




func _on_Tile_pressed():
    emit_signal("tile_pressed", number)



func _on_Tween_tween_completed(_object, _key):
    emit_signal("slide_completed", number)
```

I entered these codes for the board puzzle.

```
extends Control

export var size = 4
export var tile_size = 80
export var tile_scene: PackedScene
export var slide_duration = 0.15

var board = []
var tiles = []
var empty = Vector2()
var is_animating = false
var tiles_animating = 0

var move_count = 0
var number_visible = true
var background_texture = null

enum GAME_STATES {
    NOT_STARTED,
    STARTED,
    WON
}

var game_state = GAME_STATES.NOT_STARTED

signal game_started
signal game_won
signal moves_updated

func gen_board():
    var value = 1
    board = []
    for r in range(size):
        board.append([])
        for c in range(size):
            
            if (value == size*size):
                board[r].append(0)
                empty = Vector2(c, r)
            else:
                board[r].append(value)
                
                var tile = tile_scene.instance()
                tile.set_position(Vector2(c * tile_size, r * tile_size))
                tile.set_text(value)
                if background_texture:
                    tile.set_sprite_texture(background_texture)
                tile.set_sprite(value-1, size, tile_size)
                tile.set_number_visible(number_visible)
                tile.connect("tile_pressed", self, "on_Tile_pressed")
                tile.connect("slide_completed", self, "_on_Tile_slide_completed")
                add_child(tile)
                tiles.append(tile)
                
            value += 1

func is_board_solved():
    var count = 1
    for r in range(size):
        for c in range(size):
            if (board[r][c] != count):
                if r == c and c == size - 1 and board[r][c] == 0:
                    return true
                else:
                    return false
            count +=1
    return true
    

func print_board():
    print('------board------')
    for r in range(size):
        var row = ''
        for c in range(size):
            row += str(board[r][c]).pad_zeros(2) + ' '
        print(row)

func value_to_grid(value):
    for r in range(size):
        for c in range(size):
            if (board[r][c] == value):
                return Vector2(c, r)
    return null

func get_tile_by_value(value):
    for tile in tiles:
        if str(tile.number) == str(value):
            return tile
    return null
    

func _ready():
    tile_size = floor(get_size().x / size)
    set_size(Vector2(tile_size*size, tile_size*size))
    gen_board()
    

func _on_Tile_pressed(number):
    if is_animating:
        return
        
    if game_state == GAME_STATES.NOT_STARTED:
        scramble_board()
        game_state = GAME_STATES.STARTED
        emit_signal('game_started')
        return
        
    if game_state == GAME_STATES.WON:
        game_state = GAME_STATES.STARTED
        reset_move_count()
        scramble_board()
        emit_signal('game_started')
        return

    var tile = value_to_grid(number)
    empty = value_to_grid(0)
    
    if (tile.x != empty.x and tile.y != empty.y):
        return

    var dir = Vector2("sign(tile.x - empty.x)", "sign(tile.y, - empty.y)")

    var start = Vector2("min(tile.x, empty.x)", "min(tile.y, empty.y)")
    var end = Vector2("max(tile.x, empty.x)", "max(tile.y, empty.y)")

    for r in range(end.y, start.y - 1, -1):
        for c in range(end.x, start.x - 1, -1):
            if board[r][c] == 0:
                continue
            var object: TextureButton = get_tile_by_value(board[r][c])
            object.slide_to((Vector2(c, r)-dir) * tile_size, slide_duration)
            is_animating = true
            tiles_animating += 1

    var old_board = board.duplicate(true)
    
    if tile.y == empty.y:
        if dir.x == -1:
            board[tile.y] = slide_row(board[tile.y], 1, start.x)
        else:
            board[tile.y] = slide_row(board[tile.y], -1, end.x)

    if tile.x == empty.x:
        var column = []
        for r in range(size):
            column.append(board[r][tile.x])

        if dir.y == -1:
            column = slide_column(column, 1, start.y)
        else:
            column = slide_column(column, -1, end.y)

        for r in range(size):
            board[r][tile.x] = column[r]

    var moves_made = 0
    for r in range(size):
        for c in range(size):
            if old_board[r][c] != board[r][c]:
                moves_made += 1

    move_count += moves_made - 1
    emit_signal("moves_updated", move_count)
    
    
    var is_solved = is_board_solved()
    if is_solved:
        game_state = GAME_STATES.WON
        emit_signal("game_won")
    

func is_board_solvable(flat):
    var parity = 0
    var grid_width = size
    var row = 0
    var blank_row = 0
    for i in range(size*size):
        if i % grid_width == 0:
            row += 1

        if flat[i] == 0:
            blank_row = row
            continue

        for j in range(i+1, size*size):
            if flat[i] > flat[j] and flat[j] != 0:
                parity += 1

    if grid_width % 2 == 0:
        if blank_row % 2 == 0:
            return parity % 2 == 0
        else:
            return parity % 2 != 0
    else:
        return parity % 2 == 0
            
func scramble_board():
    reset_board()

    var temp_flat_board = []
    for i in range(size*size - 1, -1, -1):
        temp_flat_board.append(i)

    randomize()
    temp_flat_board.shuffle()
    
    var is_solvable = is_board_solvable(temp_flat_board)
    while not is_solvable:
        randomize()
        temp_flat_board.shuffle()
        is_solvable = is_board_solvable(temp_flat_board)

    for r in range(size):
        for c in range(size):
            board[r][c] = temp_flat_board[r*size + c]
            if board[r][c] != 0:
                set_tile_position(r, c, board[r][c])
    empty = value_to_grid(0)

func reset_board():
    reset_move_count()
    board = []
    for r in range(size):
        board.append(([]))
        for c in range(size):
            board[r].append(r*size + c + 1)
            if r*size + c + 1 == size * size:
                board[r][c] = 0
            else:
                set_tile_position(r, c, board[r][c])
    empty = value_to_grid(0)
    
func set_tile_position(r: int, c: int, val: int):
    var object: TextureButton = get_tile_by_value(val)
    object.set_position(Vector2(c, r) * tile_size)
    
func _process(_delta):
    var is_pressed = true
    var dir = Vector2.ZERO
    if (Input.is_action_just_pressed("move_left")):
        dir.x = -1
    elif (Input.is_action_just_pressed("move_right")):
        dir.x = 1
    elif (Input.is_action_just_pressed("move_up")):
        dir.y = -1
    elif (Input.is_action_just_pressed("move_down")):
        dir.y = 1
    else:
        is_pressed = false
    if is_pressed:
        empty = value_to_grid(0)

        var nr = empty.y + dir.y
        var nc = empty.x + dir.x
        if (nr == -1 or nc == -1 or nr >= size or nc >= size):
            return
        var tile_pressed = board[nr][nc]
        print(tile_pressed)
        _on_Tile_pressed(tile_pressed)


func slide_row(row, dir, limiter):
    var empty_index = row.find(0)
    if dir == 1:
        
        var start = row.slice(0, limiter)
        start.pop_back()
        var pre = row.slice(limiter, empty_index)
        pre.pop_back()
        var post = row.slice(empty_index, row.size())
        post.pop_front()
        return start + [0] + pre + post
    else:
        var pre = row.slice(0, empty_index)
        pre.pop_back()
        var post = row.slice(empty_index, limiter)
        post.pop_front()
        var end = row.slice(limiter, row.size() - 1)
        end.pop_front()
        return pre + post + [0] + end
    
func slide_column(column, dir, limiter):
    var empty_index = column.find(0)
    if dir == 1:
        
        var start = column.slice(0, limiter)
        start.pop_back()
        var pre = column.slice(limiter, empty_index)
        pre.pop_back()
        var post = column.slice(empty_index, column.size())
        post.pop_front()
        return start + [0] + pre + post
    else:
        var pre = column.slice(0, empty_index)
        pre.pop_back()
        var post = column.slice(empty_index, limiter)
        post.pop_front()
        var end = column.slice(limiter, column.size() - 1)
        end.pop_front()
        return pre + post + [0] + end
            
func _on_Tile_slide_completed(_number):
    tiles_animating -= 1
    if tiles_animating == 0:
        is_animating = false

func reset_move_count():
    move_count = 0
    emit_signal("moves_updated", move_count)
    
func set_tile_numbers(state):
    number_visible = state
    for tile in tiles:
        tile.set_number_visiblw(state)
        
func update_size(new_size):
    size = int(new_size)
    print('updating board size ', size)
    
    tile_size = floor(get_size().x / size)
    for tile in tiles:
        tile.queue_free()
    tiles = []
    gen_board()
    game_state = GAME_STATES.NOT_STARTED
    reset_move_count()
        
func update_background_texture(texture):
    background_texture = texture
    for tile in tiles:
        tile.set_sprite_texture(texture)
        tile.update_size(size, tile_size)
```

When I click ctr+shift+f5, the messy puzzle is also displayed, but by pressing the buttons that I defined in the input map, none of the puzzle pieces move.
Bugs are not displayed in the debug section.
I did not understand what is the existing bug.